# Codewarrior's command-line interface stops waiting for a dialog

Tags: eclipse, codewarrior

I am compiling a CodeWarrior project using cwide.

When the build is successful, everything is OK, but when there are errors, my continuous automation system blocks forever waiting for a click here:

[image: Dialog after a failure]

I invoke the build with:

```
cwidec -noSplash -data $WSWORKSPACE -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild  -build ProjectName
```

Any ideas, how to avoid that dialog?

Comment: Double check those vmargs. They might not all be valid in whatever version if Java you have.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is adding `--launcher.supressErrors`.